# Add distance field : [x,y,z,distance] from VLP-16 using ROS or velodyne driver

Tags: c++, ros, point-clouds, lidar

Velodyne lidars publish PointCloud2 messages with the fields containing :

- x, type : float32
- y, type : float32
- z, type : float32
- intensity, type : float32
- ring, type : uint16
- time, type : float32

However, I need to add distance field(output points with distance) because I needed this field as a research purpose.

Is it possible to write a node or adapt the velodyne driver to output points with that field? If so, could you possibly tell me how to achieve that?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks:)

Comment: How exactly do you want to use this distance field? The velodyne ros driver will already output a 3D pointcloud measured in meters. Depending on sampling frequency this can be solved with specific data structures.

Comment: I want to use it for segment objects of a specified width in point clouds. (web: https://github.com/AIS-Bonn/object_detection_in_laser_range_data) This project needs distance(distance of point to sensor), points(x,y,z), intensity, and rings to segment objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is not to change the velodyne driver, but since you're using ros, to leverage all the ecosystem tools built in.
For example, the velodyne [publishes a sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 topic](http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud). Then internally, using C++, ROS treats any [PointCloud2 msg into any PCL pointcloud type](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros). If you're doing serious processing of pointclouds, don't re-invent the wheel (but worse), try solving the problem with tools from PCL. Use it's pre-built filters (ex ground plane filter) and prebuilt segmentation tools (ex could [Euclidean Cluster Extraction](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/cluster_extraction.html) solve your problem?). Additionally, some of these [PCL tools are pre-wrapped in ros](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros/Tutorials/filters), to use from the launch file if you want!

Otherwise you could use PCL to add a distance parameter, by choosing the pointcloud type in ros as of type [`pcl::PointWithRange` or `pcl::PointWithViewpoint`](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/adding_custom_ptype.html#adding-custom-ptype). I don't think it'll autocompute that variable, but you can iterate through the points and compute it yourself, and the memory for it will already be allocated and localized.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am trying to achieve it:)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you likely already noticed, but specific to your comment about interfacing with that github repo package above, looking at the `segmenter.h` file, when it says "velodyne input" the callback is really (if you follow the typedef's) a `pcl::PointCloud<InputPoint>` -> `pcl::PointCloud<laser_segmentation::PointXYZIDR>`, where the laser_segmentation point type is a custom PCL type made in the `point_type.h` file.

Comment: _I think this means that you can just provide the velodyne topic as-is to this package._ If not, then as I suggested, you can have a node that includes his `point_type.h`, subscribes to the ros PointCloud2 topic as a `pcl::PointCloud<laser_segmentation::PointXYZIDR>`, loop through the points providing the missing distance data, and publish it again as a PointCloud2 topic to that github package. *But* the readme says it takes a velodyne puck input, which is PointCloud2, and he last updated it only 2 months ago, so I'm sure if this doesn't work, you could leave an Issue and the author may help.

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in getting back to you and thank you so much for providing these suggestions for me:) Now I can add distance field and publish it successfully.